# What is the proper way to close a sql db connection?

Tags: mysql, database, go

I am using sql with Go, using the [mysql driver](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql) and `database/sql`.

While reading about it I found that this driver handles the things related to connection pooling itself and db, `err := db.Open("conn string")` returns the connection pool instead of a single connection and when we use `db.Query("some query")`, it actually picks a free connection from connection pool (if no connection in pool is free it opens a new one) and uses it.

Please correct me, if I am wrong in my above understanding.

Now my question is, what happens when I call `db.Close()`:

1. Will it close all connections in the connection pool?
2. Will it close then even if they they are passed to different goroutines and are being used there?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Yes, of course.

Comment: Doc of [`DB.Close()`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Close): _"Close closes the database and **prevents new queries from starting. Close then waits for all queries that have started processing on the server to finish.**

It is rare to Close a DB, as the DB handle is meant to be long-lived and shared between many goroutines."_

Comment: @AmanPatel also note the last paragraph of documentation on [Open](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Open) *"The returned DB is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines and maintains its own pool of idle connections. Thus, the Open function should be called just once. **It is rarely necessary to close a DB**."*

Comment: Thank you all , and @mkopriva , i read exactly the same thing in docs , but my observation was a bit different so i got confused.

Comment: Basically the problem is when I open a db conn using db , err := db.Open(...) , and pass it to goroutines (around 20) performing different queries , ideally they should use connection from the db connection pool pointed by the db object , but my sql db was showing hell lot of open connections. Though i was also calling defer db.Close() , but i dont believe that it had to do anything with it

Comment: @AmanPatel pretty much any other object from that package that *can* be closed, should be closed as soon as one is done with it. For example, one very common mistake, that causes a Go program to run out of available connections and crash, is to not close the `*sql.Rows` object returned from the `Query` / `QueryContext` methods.